# How did team 1 of animals find team 2 of animals?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-secret-lives-of-pets

In The Secret Lives of Pets,

> Two dogs from Manhattan, named Max and Duke, get lost in Brooklyn. They are pursued by abandoned animals who intend to harm them, led by an angry rabbit named Snowball. The two groups clash on the Brooklyn Bridge,

and it looks like curtains for our protagonists, when

> friendly pets led by the fluffy dog "Gidget" find them and defeat the attackers.

**My question is this:** How did Gidget et al. know where to find Max and Duke, and get to them in time?

Apologies if this was explained in the movie. I kept falling asleep.

Answer (score 1):

When the 'Gidget' group visits the sewers to see if they abandon pet group have seen Max and Duke, they overhear Snowball saying that Max and Duke were in Brooklyn.  I suppose that is how they know they are in Brooklyn, but how they specifically locate them in Brooklyn, is not really clear unless they have the hawk do aerial surveillance.